# How do I get FMDB on project target iOS 7.1 (below 8)?

Tags: ios, ios7.1, fmdb

I installed FMDB using pods because I need to access a local sqlite database. I liked the library, but unfortunately, if I put a deployment target under iOS 8, I get this error at build

```
ld: embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later (@rpath/FMDB.framework/FMDB) for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

There is a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carthage support for frameworks was added in 2.6. For now, you should be able to specify <strike>2.5.2</strike> 2.5 in the `Podfile` and you should be able to Support iOS 7. I've posted [an issue](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/issues/455) on github on this and we'll see if the Cocoapods configuration can be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the advise! Unfortunately I get this error when calling pod install: [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `FMDB (~> 2.5.2)` required by `Podfile`

Comment: It looks like you can do 2.5.